# Is there a way to distinguish internally defined children from externally defined ones in QML?

Tags: qt, count, qml, parent, children

I have defined a `MyElement` element (in the MyElement.qml file) as the following:

```
Rectangle {
    Item {
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.warn(children.length)
    }
}
```

Let's call the `Item` element defined within `MyElement` the *internal* child. Now, I'm using the `MyElement` element in the following way:

```
MyElement {
    Item {
    }
}
```

Here another one `Item` element is used as a child of `MyElement`. Let's call this `Item` element the *external* child. To understand my question below one should clearly understand the difference between internal and external children.

The output for the presented code will be **2**, i.e. both `Item` elements are calculated as children.

In the future I want to iterate in the block `Component.onCompleted` only over external children, not over internal (external children go after internal). But for this I have to know a children index from which I have to start (in the given example this index is **1**). Is there a way to get this index or, in other words, the number of internal children? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no internal mechanism in Qt to distinguish internal children from those which are defined outside of the own QML definition.
My workaround is as follow

```
//MyElement.qml
Rectangle {
    id: root
    readonly property Item last_item: lastone

    Item {
        id: someitem
    }

    Item {
        id: lastone
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var external_started = false;
        for(var i = 0 ; i < root.children.length ; ++i)
        {
               if(external_started)
                   console.log(root.children[i].toString(), 'is external');
               else if(root.children[i]===last_item)
                   external_started = true;
        }

    }
}
```

and

```
MyElement {
    Item {
      objectName: 'I am external'
    }
}
```

It's a ***dirty*** hack but it works.
I'm saving a reference to the last item in a readonly property called `last_item` and that will distinguish my last item in qml definition.
Other items which are added outside of the qml file, will be placed after this item in the children list.

Comment: @Jordan, I edited my answer for a better workaround.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But for me it is enough to know that there are no standard ways to distinguish internal and external children.

Comment: @Jordan, actually, they are not different from the compiler perspective. I think that this is gonna change in Qt 6.